# Applications only connecting to target by using public IP address

Tags: windows-10, networking

atm i got problems with 3 applications showing same issues.

1. **LorianBoard** (Software to control OBS Studio). I can control the program with an android app through my Wifi via port 9423. Some time ago everything was working well. But, since 2-3 weeks i cannot not connect the android app with LorianBoard via wifi by using the local IP (192.168.###.##) of my computer. I opened port 9423 at the local firewall.. The confusing point: When i use the public ip address given by my ISP (like 91.130.#.###) the android app does connect successfully to Lorian Board.
2. I'm using softphones like e.g. **PhonerLite** or **microsip**. They
   communicate via port 5060. Same problem as Point 1.
3. **Bitvise SSH Client**: I got a Raspi 4 connected to the internet router via LAN cable. When i try to connect with SSH (Port 22) to the Raspi's IP it doesn't connect and Bitvise is showing error: *Connection failed. FlowSocketConnector: Failed to connect to target address. Windows error 10013*. When i use the public IP as mentioned in Point 1 the connection can be established.

However, i tried the netsh way and had a look if the ports 22, 9423 or 5060 are bind or something.
I completely disabled Windows Firewall.
Nothing helped.

I can only connect from my Computer or to my Computer by using the public IP.

Did somebody of you have similar issues?

Comment: Can you ping the server (the PC that runs LorianBoard), it would be helpful know if it's a network (layer4 and below) or a software (layer7 and below) issue. As far as I understand you disabled all the firewalls so it can not be that, right?

Comment: @Albin Yes, i can ping the PC and i can also ping all hosts and clients from the PC. The problem also occures when the firewall is disabled at all.